# C# Random number hits far often than expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, random

We have this random number generator:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
bool PiratePrincess = rnd.Next(1, 5000) == 1;
```

This is called on every page view.  There should be a 1/5000 chance the variable is `True`.  However, in ~15,000 page views this has been `True` about 20 times!

Can someone explain why this is the case, and how to prevent this so it is roughly 1/5000 times?  It's not important at all for this to be truly random.

**Edit: Should this do the trick?**

```
Random rnd = new Random();
bool PiratePrincess = (rnd.Next() + ThisUser.UserID + ThisUser.LastVisit.Ticks + DateTime.Now.Ticks) % 5000 == 1;
```

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is that you're creating a new `Random` for each page.  You need a persistant `Random` on which you will call `.Next()` for each page, otherwise you create a new `Random` based on the default method of creating a `Random` which may not have good random characteristics.  The other possibility is that `Random` simply doesn't have that good of random characteristics (being not truly random) and you might have to come up with a new way to generate your random number.

Comment: If you call this in a tight loop, you probably will get the same result multiple times since new Random() uses the current timestamp as a seed.  If you call several times before the tick count of the timestamp changes, you will get the same result each time.  Given this is a web scenario that seems less likely, but look for a similar issue.

Comment: @mydogisbox: The default method is to use the current tick count.  Unless the 15,000 page views are something like per second, that's most likely not the issue.

Comment: @EricJ. I'm not sure what you're saying.  Didn't I make essentially the same argument you did?

Answer (score 8):

How quickly are these pageviews coming in?  `new Random` will initialize based on the current time, so many overlapping requests will get the same random seed.  Randomize the seed based on the remote IP address hashed with the current time for more uniqueness.

That said, it is possible to flip a coin 20 times and get heads every single time.  It's a legitimate random outcome.

Edit:this will do it

```
var r = new Random(
    Convert.ToInt32(
        (ThisUser.UserID ^ ThisUser.LastVisit.Ticks ^ DateTime.Now.Ticks) & 0xFFFFFFFF)
    );

var isPiratePrincess = (r.Next (5000) == 42);
```

Comment: I know it's a legitimate outcome but I think the most likely case here is the RNG is doing something I'm not expecting it to!

Comment: Your update should instead read:

`Random rnd = new Random(ThisUser.UserID ^ ThisUser.LastVisit.Ticks ^ DateTime.Now.Ticks);
bool PiratePrincess = (rnd.Next(1, 5000) == 1);`

Comment: It's an outcome that literally has a one-in-a-million chance of being "legitimate." If the chance of a bug in your code is substantially more than one-in-a-million, I wouldn't call it legitimate as per [Bayes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem)

Comment: @Insta that overflows all the time, just adding them's going to be ok right?

Comment: As long as it's done in the constructor of the `Random`.  I'm curious why it overflows, as it's just an XOR.  Adding them might cause the same problem.  I'll update my post after trying something else.

Comment: @TomGullen: it was overflowing because (at a minimum) `DateTime.Now.Ticks` is a long, and the seed takes an `int`.  So, adding them could potentially hit the same issue if you overflow an `int`.  My updated code truncates the upper 32 bits so it will fit into an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

You only need instantiate a single instance of `Random`, thus:

```
public class Widget
{
  private static rngInstance = new Random() ;

  public bool IsPiratePrincess()
  {
    bool isTrue = rngInstance.Next(1, 5000) == 1 ;
    return isTrue ;
  }

}
```

Pseudo-random number generators implement a series. Each time you instantiate a new instance, it seeds itself based on (among other things) the current time-of-day and it starts a new series.

If you instantiate a new one on each invocation, and the instantiations are frequent enough, you'll likely see similarities in the stream of pseudo-random values generated, since the initial seed values are likely to be close to each other.

**Edited to note:** Since `System.Random` is not thread-safe, you probably want to wrap in such a way as to make it thread-safe. This class (from [Getting Random Numbers in Thread-Safe Way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/02/19/9434171.aspx)) will do the trick. It uses a per-thread static field and instantiates a RNG instance for each thread:

```
public static class RandomGen2 
{ 
  private static Random _global = new Random(); 
  [ThreadStatic] 
  private static Random _local;

  public static int Next() 
  { 
      Random inst = _local; 
      if (inst == null) 
      { 
        int seed; 
        lock (_global) seed = _global.Next(); 
        _local = inst = new Random(seed); 
      } 
    return inst.Next(); 
  } 
}
```

I'm a little dubious about seeding each RNG instance with the output of another RNG. That strikes me a liable to bias the results. I think it might be better to use the default constructor.

Another approach would be to latch each access to a single RNG instance:

```
public static class RandomGen1 
{ 
  private static Random _inst = new Random();

  public static int Next() 
  { 
    lock (_inst) return _inst.Next(); 
  } 
}
```

But that has some performance issues (bottleneck, plus overhead of a lock on each call).

Comment: Thanks for the code, how would I do a 1/5000 chance with this though?

Comment: Change it to use the overload of `Next()` that you prefer. Or, take the random integer *x* returned by `Next()` ( 0 <= *x* <= `int.MaxValue` ) modulo 5000: `bool fHit = ( 0 == rng.Next() % 5000 ? true : false ) ;`

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new random number generator with a new seed every time you're generating a number.  The distribution of the values you get will have more to do with the seed than it does with the distribution characteristics of the algorithm being used.

I'm  not sure what the best way is to achieve a more even distribution.  If your traffic volume is low enough, you could use a hit counter on the page on check for divisibility by 5000, but that kind of approach would quickly run into contention problems if you tried to scale it.

Comment: I can have a logged in user ID, would this suffice?

Comment: As I stated in my comment, the best way to achieve a more even distribution is to only have one instance of `Random`.

Comment: I'm not sure what your use case is, but the user ID wouldn't change from page hit to page hit, meaning user ID alone doesn't give enough to do an evenly distributed 1 in 5000 page hit selection.

Comment: @mydogisbox: asp.net doesn't naturally lend itself to that type of persistence.  What are your thoughts about how to implement that?

Comment: I don't have much experience with asp so maybe that is a non-optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is really the seed (as many people including myself suspect), you can either persist an instance of Random() (which will cause concurrency issues under high volume, but is fine for ~15,000 hits per day), or you can introduce more entropy to the seed.

If this were for an application where you do not want determined people to break the pseudo-random characteristics, you should look into software or hardware that generates a good seed on your server (poker websites often use a hardware entropy generator).

If you just want a good distribution and don't expect people to try to hack your solution, consider just blending various sources of entropy (the current timestamp, hash of the user's user agent string, the IPv4 address or hash of the IPv6 address, etc.).

UPDATE: You mention you have the user ID too.  Hash that for entropy along with one or more of the items mentioned above, especially the ticks from the current timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You can get exactly 1/5000 if you avoid `Random` altogether.

```
vals = Enumerable.Repeat(false, 4999).ToList();
vals.Add(true);

// this or an in-memory shuffle if that is a concern
isPiratePrincess = vals.OrderBy(v => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();

// remove values as it's queried & reset when empty.
```

The problem with using Random here is that you could be in a state where 20 in 15K were legitimately hit.  In the next several thousand iterations, you'll hit a cold streak that regresses you towards the expected mean.

Comment: How slow is this?  It's called on every page view and we get a fair number of them so want to avoid anything too heavy.

Comment: Assuming you have a state server that manages this for the _exact_ count across sessions, it should be pretty quick.  You can make it much quicker by avoiding Enumerable (used to show off the algorithm) and initializing with arrays and using a Knuth shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

The random number generator uses the current time as a seed for the random number generator. So, if two come in at the same time, they could theoretically have the same seed. If you want your numbers to be unique with each other, you might want to use the same random number generator for all instances of the page.